# how to hide images from embed twitter timeline?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter

I tried everything. 
From CSS to jQuery and uncheck Auto-expand photos.

This is my embed code:

```
  <a class="twitter-timeline"
  href=""
  data-widget-id="" 
  data-chrome="noheader footer noborders noscrollbar transparent" 
  data-tweet-limit="5"
  data-link-color="#6AC829"
  data-border-color="#FFFFFF"
  lang="EN" data-theme="light"
  height="100"
  width="800" 
  data-screen-name=""
  data-show-replies="false"
  data-aria-polite="assertive">
  </a>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
 ! function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
         p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
     if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
         js = d.createElement(s);
         js.id = id;
         js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBe fore(js, fjs);
     }
 }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");

 window.setTimeout(function() {
     $(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".e-entry-title").css("font-size", "12px");
     $(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".inline-media").css("display", "none");
     $(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".tweet").css("font-size", "12px");
     $(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".p-name.customisable-highlight").css("font-size", "12px");
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks for editing satpal!

Comment: could you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that I have a solution. I've tested in all major browsers. Sorry to be so late to this.

With the update on March 3rd this is again relevant.

https://blog.twitter.com/2016/a-new-improved-embedded-timeline

First step, wrap the timeline in a container such as a div. Next, add this jQuery to the footer or in a `jQuery(document).ready();`

```
jQuery('.twitter-block').on('DOMSubtreeModified propertychange',"#twitter-  widget-0", function() {
  jQuery(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".timeline-Tweet-media").css("display", "none");
  jQuery(".twitter-block").css("height", "100%");
});
```

Target the container ie '.twitter-block', and the ID of the iframe "#twitter-widget-0". The second line hides the media (images/video) and the third resizes the iframe. This should work on page load, as well as for any dynamic updates made in the timeline.

Comment: I tried to apply your solution but seems that it doesn't work anymore, currently, the timeline has weir name classes, 'timeline-Tweet-media' was removed.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution bro, hope this help.
You have to create iframe.css file in your style folder then in your script add this:

```
      $(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.t-block').on('DOMSubtreeModified propertychange',"#twitter-widget-0", function() {
      var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
      cssLink.href = "/stylesheets/iframe.css"; 
      cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
      cssLink.type = "text/css";

      $(this.contentDocument.documentElement).find("body").append(cssLink);
    });
  })
```

.t-block it's just a container.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I manage to remove the Twitter media.

1. You will have to create the Twitter timeline using the js, you may refer to this link for the details, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-factory-functions.
2. Once you created the Twitter timeline, you can use the callback function to remove the media.

Here is the code for your reference,

```html
<div id='tweet-timeline'></div>
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
  twttr.widgets.createTimeline({
    sourceType: 'profile',
    screenName: 'TwitterDev'
  }, document.getElementById('tweet-timeline'), {
    tweetLimit: '1',
    chrome: 'noheader, nofooter, noborders, transparent, noscrollbar',
    related: 'twitterdev,twitterapi'
  }).then(function (el) {
    $("#twitter-widget-0").contents().find(".timeline-Tweet-media").css("display", "none");
    console.log('Embedded a timeline.')
  });
</script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/4juqoazd/

Answer (score -3):

If you uncheck the box in the Auto-expand photos  box in the admin tool, it takes a while for the change to be shown. You may want to uncheck it, and then give it a day or 2.

Comment: This checkbox has been removed from the website.