# Remove images from twitter timeline embed

Tags: jquery, twitter

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731150/how-to-hide-images-from-embed-twitter-timeline)  but it seems the previous answers no longer apply in 2023.

I am embedding a twitter feed but want to remove images from the feed.  Previous answers suggest using jQuery like this  but it no longer works https://jsfiddle.net/4juqoazd/

This is the timeline embed.  I've also tried with the code from the jsfiddle above.

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/CommForests?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"></a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```